# Mobile minibrowser: how to reload image while maintaing page offset position?

Tags: javascript, browser, mobile, offset

In mobile web minibrowsers, it seems that the `window` object makes no sense — since there's only one window to show. Therefore, things like `window.pageYOffset=320` make no sense (as far as I can tell).

Given a simple example such as a map zoomin/zoomout such as

```
<html>
<head>
<title>zoom.html</title>
<script language="javascript">
var zoom=15;
var vpos=window.pageYOffset;
var key="whatever-your-Google-Maps-site-key-is";
function setImgSrc(z) {
    document.getElementById('img').src=
    "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Lisbon,Portugal&zoom="
    +zoom+"&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key="+key;
}
function zoomin()   
{ if(zoom<=18) zoom++; vpos=window.pageYOffset; setImgSrc(zoom); }
function zoomout()  
{ if(zoom>=1)  zoom--; vpos=window.pageYOffset; setImgSrc(zoom); }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:setImgSrc(15);">
<h1>zoom</h1>
<p><img id="img" alt="Lisbon,Portugal"/></p><p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:zoomin()">[+]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:zoomout()">[&ndash;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</p><hr></body></html>
```

which seems to work well on desktop browsers; so I ask: how can I indicate that, on updating the page (`onclick` doesn't seem to work on minibrowsers, but `href` does) it should offset the page to the previous position? 
(For other reasons, simply (re)loading the page to a given `name`d anchor isn't working on the problem I'm dealing with.)

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it lovely when you answer your own questions? Hmmm...

Anyway, according to [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/window.shtml), some properties/functions for the JavaScript (JScript?) `window` object have different representations according to the choice of browser (Firefox, IE, etc.). Therefore, a possible page vertical offset function would be

```
function setPageVPos(w,vpos) {
  try { w.scrollTo(0,vpos); } catch(e) {}
  try { w.document.body.scrollTop(vpos); } catch(e) {}
}
```

The first tries with the `window.scrollTo` implementation in Firefox browsers, and the second tries with the `document.body.scrollTop` implementation in IE browsers. I've tested in both Firefox (desktop) browser and in a HP iPaq IE-like (mobile) minibrowser and works on both.